# JMeter - issues attempting to generate SOAP Security header using JSR223 PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter, soapui

Putting together a SOAP Request in `JMeter`. My request is valid, as it succeeds in `SOAPUI`. My issue is getting the request's Security header populated. I'm attempting to generate the security header with the code below, but I keep encountering the following exception:

> 2016/07/07 09:24:44 ERROR - jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 PreProcessor.2 javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
>
> `import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init; import com.sun.org.apache. . . .` : 
>   JMert : at Line: 78 : in file: inline evaluation of:
>
> `import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init; import com.sun.org.apache. . . .` : ( privateKey ) 
>        in inline evaluation of: ``import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init; import com.sun.org.apache. . . . '' at line number 78

As far as I can tell, the privateKey is properly declared in the code I'm using. As expected, when I run the testplan in JMeter the SOAP response is that the request is missing the security headers.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.c14n.Canonicalizer;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.signature.XMLSignature;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.transforms.Transforms;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Constants;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.XMLUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.SoapSampler;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

//write sampler body into "signature.xml" file

String body = sampler.getXmlData();
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("signature.xml"),body);
File signatureFile = new File("signature.xml");

//X509 properties

String keystoreType = "JKS";
String keystoreFile = "C:/jMeterTest/resources/abbazabba.jks";
String keystorePass = "XYZ";
String privateKeyAlias = "abba";
String privateKeyPass = "XYZ";
String certificateAlias = "abbazabba";


Element element = null;
String BaseURI = signatureFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
//SOAP envelope to be signed


//get the private key used to sign, from the keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
ks.load(fis, keystorePass.toCharArray());
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
//create basic structure of signature
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
String request = sampler.getXmlData();
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes());
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);
in.close();
Init.init();
XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc, BaseURI, XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA);

element = doc.getDocumentElement();
element.normalize();
element.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Header").item(0).appendChild(sig.getElement());

{
 Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
 transforms.addTransform(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
 //Sign the content of SOAP Envelope
 sig.addDocument("", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
}

//Signing procedure
{
 X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(certificateAlias);
 sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
 sig.addKeyInfo(cert.getPublicKey());
 sig.sign(privateKey);
}

//write signature to file
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(signatureFile);
XMLUtils.outputDOMc14nWithComments(doc, f);
f.close();

//set sampler's XML data from file
String request = FileUtils.readFileToString(signatureFile);
sampler.setXmlData(request);
```

Further, if I comment out `sig.sign(privateKey);` the security information is populated in the security header, however the formatting and data insertion is incorrect and the request fails with Invalid Security message.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by making the following changes:

Changed

```
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
```

TO:

```
java.security.Key privateKey = (java.security.Key) ks.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
```

also moved

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
ks.load(fis, keystorePass.toCharArray());
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
```

and

```
 Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
 transforms.addTransform(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
 //Sign the content of SOAP Envelope
 sig.addDocument("", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
```

in with the signing procedure.

In order to get the security information placed within `<Security:wsse>` I modified

```
element.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Header").item(0).appendChild(sig.getElement());
```

to

```
element.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Header").item(0).getElementsByTagName("wsse:Security").item(0).appendChild(sig.getElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web service expects only client-side request SSL encryption and no other security mechanisms are in place you don't even need any scripting.

1. Change your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) implementation to **Java**
2. Add the following lines to *system.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/jMeterTest/resources/abbazabba.jks
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=XYZ
   ```
3. If needed specify which key to use via [Keystore Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration)

That's it. See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](http://How%20to%20Set%20Your%20JMeter%20Load%20Test%20to%20Use%20Client%20Side%20Certificates) for detailed information on configuring JMeter-side requests encryption.

Comment: That was my first line of thinking, and that was unsuccessful. I've now found a fix for the problem detailed above, but am still working to put together the final pieces of the security header puzzle.